# "Fake" argument into class constructor

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a js API and I have to instantiate a class that requires a `<div>` element in its constructor. However this is only used by the class to do some rendering in the element and I don't need it, I just want to use a method of this class.

I came up with this which seems better than linking to a random `<div>` element of the page :

```
service = new API.service(document.createElement("div"));
service.useMethod();
```

Do you have any better ideas about how to do this ? I don't really know what is good practice in this case.

FYI the class I'm actually using is [`google.maps.places.PlacesService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) from Google maps javascript API in order to use the method `getDetails` on some info I retrieved earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is OK (I don't know a better approach).

But the issue:
This required node isn't there for fun, the API will print there Copyright-details for the requests(if there are any), and these details **must** be visible(at least when you display something that is based on the data returned by the service).

So your approach is correct from a programmers view, but it would violate the TOS

Comment: This is not done in order to "hack" google maps, it is completely clear in my application that I'm using google maps. The method I described here is used as a workaround for when the user doesn't select himself the address and is wrapped into a regular use of the service.

Comment: It's not sufficient when you e.g. show the google-logo to clarify that you use google-maps. The copyright-owners of the data returned by the service may be different than google(e.g. yellow pages)....these copyrights must be printed too